# remove "index.php" from permalinks

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, urls, rewrite-rules, mod-rewrite

I have been trying to find a solution. but I can't..

my links are all `domain.com/index.php/post_name/`

I really want to remove `/index.php`

I have searched and found some... saying I need to add these.. but it's not working ..

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I am using 3.5.2 wp.

Please let me know if you know anything about it.

Comment: are you using apache and is mod_rewrite enabled? this is probably a question for your particular host.

Comment: i have no idea. i am just using a web hosting service.

Comment: should I disable to remove "index.php"?

Comment: @pulla You need to find out more about your web hosting service and what sort of configuration it runs on.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Go to your WP-ADMIN-->Settings-->Permalink and use the permalink structure change there, if it generate any `.htaccess` file copy the content and update your `.htaccess` file.

Or Check if your hosting `mod_rewrite` is enable by creating a file `phpinfo.php` with content,

```
<?php phpinfo();?>
```

Upload this file and browse via Browser. So you know which modules are enabled. You need mod_rewrite enable to remove `index.php` from URL.

More details Check [this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Using_.22Pretty.22_permalinks)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried but I don't know it's not really working. it could be the hosting problem. I removed all and installed. nothing has be changed.

Comment: Facing the same issue.
Removing index.php in under wordpress permalink give error "The requested URL /wordpress/test-page/ was not found on this server."

Answer (score 6):

Had exactly same issue. But in my case `mod_rewrite` was not installed at all for apache. I just installed it with

`sudo a2enmod rewrite`

and then changed my `Permalink Settings`. Worked like a charm.

Hope it helps.

Comment: rewrite module is already enabled in my case

Comment: for me, rewrite module already enabled, but `Permalink Settings` not generate .htaccess (already parent and current folder have 777 permission)