# Permalinks Messed up

Tags: permalinks

I am trying to fix a problem, the links are all messed up and look like

[image]

I have tried this code in the public_html folder in a .htaccess file, the links are now working with index.php/%postname%/ but I need to get rid of the index.php

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any Help would be amazing. Thanks

Comment: to solve that you need to install and load mod_rewrite on your server

Comment: Can you explain a little more?

Comment: Please see this [link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/105795/remove-index-php-from-permalinks/#answer-105809) , I think it will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of searching and reading, 
This is how I solved the Problem.

Step 1: Create a .htaccess file in the root folder and put this code there.

```
# BEGIN
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END
```

Step 2: is Mentioned [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#PATHINFO:_.22Almost_Pretty.22)

[image]