# Remove index.php from URL (WP installed in subdirectory)

Tags: permalinks, site-url

I am trying to remove the annoying "index.php" from my URL. WP is installed at /www/html/wordpress. I already tried removing index.php from permalink and changing .htaccess as suggested [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/105795/remove-index-php-from-permalinks), but none worked.

I think I should somehow tell the thing where wordpress is installed. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: In "settings", "General Settings", which site url is set?

Comment: you've verified that mod_rewrite is installed and working?

Comment: The site url is www.myurl.com (of course with /index.php/%postname% for permalink).  And mod_rewrite is installed and working. I was able to fix this on my other server, where WP is installed at root, but not on this one. No idea why!